# java regex help

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with the following format:

```
String str = "someString(anotherString)(lastString)";
```

I wanted to replace the lastString inside the last brackets, i.e new String should be

```
newStr = "someString(anotherString)(modified)";
```

I am using regex with `"\\(([^\\}]+)\\)$"` pattern.

But I am unable to change only the last content inside brackets.
The above regex gives me the output:

```
"someString(modified)";
```

I just want to replace the content of the last brackets, any characters can appear infront of last bracket.

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the code you're using to replace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)\\(  # match opening parenthesis\n" +
    "[^()]*   # match 0 or more characters except parentheses\n" +
    "\\)      # match closing parenthesis\n" +
    "$        # match the end of the string", "(modified)");
```

So far, this is not allowing for whitespace between the closing parenthesis and the end of the string. You might want to insert a `\\s*` before the `$` if you need to handle that case, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo in your expression. Replace the curly brackets with a regular one, and I think it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourString.replaceAll("(.+\\(.+\\)\\()[^\\}]+(\\)$)", "$1modified$2")
```